# Creating an Excel trigger to automatically generate a Word document upon row addition

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a sheet in Excel that has rows automatically added throughout the week. These rows contain data that I want to use to fill in a template Microsoft word document and save that document (Or immediately email it out).

I tried experimenting with mail merge, but I don't want to have to manually start the process, rather I want these documents to automatically be generated every time a new row is added to the spreadsheet.

Is there any way to set up some type of trigger in Excel so that when a new row is added that data automatically fills a template and generates a new document?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, look into the `Worksheet_Change()` event and how to access Word documents from Excel.

Comment: Hi, I saw your post "https://superuser.com/questions/1468776/does-excel-auto-refresh-run-when-the-excel-workbook-is-closed"  in other community, I am trying to achieve the exactly same flow of updating Excel without keeping it open. Can you please share the steps you have done. I don't have enough points to comment there so had to comment in stack. It would be great if you share the steps for that flow. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Please respond to my comment.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - You can write a .sh script that opens your excel sheet and set your excel sheet to update on every open. You can then use your computers program scheduler to run this script on an interval. The only thing to keep in mind is that the host computer has to be running for this to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I'll check on that.